# Bulk delete via insert - full undo space

Tags: sql, oracle, undo, bulk

i have a table with 100 million of records. 
I want delete 60% of it. Now i read that i should copy the table and insert the valid values.(because its faster)
 
Example:
`INSERT INTO Person_New SELECT * FROM Person_old where p.name is not null.`

**Problem:**
After a few minutes my undo- space is full AND i can't! resize it because i had no permissions for it.

**Question:**
Should i split the insert in many parts for example with id range? Or is there a better way?

Edit for first comment **Error-Output**:
 
ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace ...

Comment: Are you sure that is your UNDO space?

Comment: yes i add the message. Or i understand something wrong there?

Comment: So try to perform an insert with the /*+APPEND*/ hint. To perform a direct-path insert.

Comment: Let me answer this question with a suitable example. One second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option is to avoid the UNDO generation using a DDL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON_NEW NOLOGGING AS
   SELECT * FROM Person_old where p.name is not null
```

The `NOLOGGING` is to avoid the REDO generation and perform the creation faster.

However, if you must perform an `INSERT`, consider a direct-path insert using the `/*+APPEND*/` hint:

```
INSERT /*+APPEND*/ INTO PERSON_NEW
  SELECT * FROM Person_old where p.name is not null
```

Creating the table PERSON_NEW with the `NOLOGGING` attribute it will be useful (and also dangerous), but using the `NOLOGGING` attribute inside the DML operation take no effect.

Comment: i cant test it at the moment, but i looks like that what i needed. If it works i mark your answer later as right. Thank you for this good explanation!

Comment: No problem. It is impossible to know if it will help you because we don't know your hardware configuration and oracle installation configuration. But I am sure that the concepts above will help you in some way :)